# $(shell tput sgr0) in Makefile cause "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Tags: bash, makefile, tput

I have a `Makefile` with `tput` color variables

```
_OFF := $(shell tput sgr0)
BG_RED := $(shell tput setab 1)

$(info TERM1=${BG_RED}${TERM}${_OFF}_xxx)

all:
    @echo TERM2=${BG_RED}${TERM}${_OFF}_xxx
```

The second prompt will give out an error

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo TERM2=xterm-256color_xxx'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The interesting thing is even it report an error, but the word `xterm-256color` in error message `` /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `echo TERM2=xterm-256color_xxx'` ``  actually has red background color, and the following `_xxx` has normal background color.

Is it a bug? or is there anything wrong to my code?

I am using MacOS `11.6.1`, GNU bash `3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)`, GNU Make `3.81`, tput `ncurses 5.7.20081102`

Comment: The `echo TERM2=...` recipe must be valid shell syntax. If your make variables `BG_RED`, `TERM` or `_OFF_` expand to characters that make the recipe invalid you get errors when the recipe is executed. Very likely one of these shell variables contain parentheses. Try to single-quote the string: `echo TERM2='${BG_RED}${TERM}${_OFF}_xxx'`.

Comment: It works on Linux.  It would be helpful to include the output of the two tput commands piped to `od -a`.  Otherwise agree with @RenaudPacalet to quote the value.

Comment: Perhaps not related to your problem, but you claim to use bash; however, the error message does not come from _bash_, but from _sh_.

Comment: @allan-wind I tried on Amazon Linux 2 and it has same error. the `tput sgr0 | od -a` on linux and my mac are same ```0000000  esc   (   B esc   [   m
0000006```
@renaud-pacalet it works if quote it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Jinyu update question with new data instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the value being set as your `tput sgr0` returns a `(`:

```
@echo TERM2='${BG_RED}${TERM}${_OFF}_xxx'
```

If you want make to use bash instead of sh, then you need the SHELL variable:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment from @Renaud Pacalet and @Allan Wind. Quote the echo string can fix the syntax error.

```
BG_RED := $(shell tput setab 1)
_OFF := $(shell tput sgr0)

$(info TERM1=${BG_RED}${TERM}${_OFF}_xxx)

all:
    @echo 'TERM2=${BG_RED}${TERM}${_OFF}_xxx'
```

According to the hint from @Allan Wind, I think the problem is there is a `(` in `tput sgr0` output

```
$ tput sgr0 | od -a                                                                                                                 
0000000  esc   (   B esc   [   m
0000006
```